# How to permanently set JEKYLL_ENV=production for Jekyll build?

Tags: jekyll, config

#### Is there some way to set the `JEKYLL_ENV=production` flag permanently?

In the [Jekyll Build Command Options](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/) documentation, it says that to build in `production` mode versus `development` mode, one has to run the build command with the `JEKYLL_ENV` flag, like so:

```
JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build
```

I've already tried adding `JEKYLL_ENV=production` and `env: production`, as well as using an `.env` file.

#### Update

Tested and working solution:

```
echo 'export JEKYLL_ENV=production' >> ~/.bashrc | # add to ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc                                   # reload ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add this line in your `.bashrc`

```
export JEKYLL_ENV=production
```

Comment: Simple and elegant, thank you.  Quick question:  I simply `exit`ed to use the updated `.bashrc` as it wasn't working until I did.  Is there some better way to accomplish that, something like `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: I only know these two methods